# Why does "echo" ignore its first argument sometimes?

Tags: shell, posix, command-line-arguments, dash-shell

The output of this code seems to depend on the option I give (`-n` or `-a`) but I simply don't understand the reason.
Here's the portion of the code that doesn't work (just the code itself + outputs):

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE="/path/to/some/textfile"

[ $# -eq 0 ] && echo "No arguments. Exiting.." && exit 1
[ $1 != "-n" ] && [ $1 != "-a" ] && echo "No new default usernames. Exiting" && exit 1
echo $@
echo
newusernames=`echo "$@"|cut -d' ' -f2-`
printf "'$newusernames' $mode as default usernames in $FILE\n"
```

Running it and giving some arguments in both ways:

```
scriptname -a word1 word2 word3
```

Gives:

```
-a word1 word2 word3

'word1 word2 word3'  as default usernames in path/to/textfile
```

While..:

```
scriptname -n word1 word2 word3
```

Gives:

```
word1 word2 word3
'word2 word3'  as default usernames in path/to/textfile
```

`$mode` is just a var that should be set in either two cases.
As shown the output is really different while this shouldn't happen.

Please note that I'm aware that this is not the most correct way to pass shell arguments in a script. I'm just trying to understand the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: `[ $1 != "-n" ]` is quoting the wrong thing. You don't need to quote `-n`; you _do_ need to quote `$1`. Thus, `[ "$1" != -n ]`

Comment: ...otherwise, `yourprogram '*'` will let the `*` be replaced with a list of filenames in the current directory when `[` tries to run.

Comment: Beyond that, though... could you please try to re-title this so the title is itself a self-contained question? Something that talks about "this shell code" is a question that can't be understood until _after_ someone clicks through and reads the body, but the purpose of a title is to let someone figure out if the content in the body is interesting to them.

Comment: `echo $@` likewise is buggy -- see further discussion of why quotes are essential even for `echo` at [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second case expands to this:

```sh
echo -n word1 word2 word3
```

and `echo -n` can be special (and seems to be, in this case): it's interpreted as an option to `echo` to not print a trailing newline character.

One solution could be to use

```sh
shift
newusernames=$(echo "$*")
```

to remove the parameter first, or even more robust:

```sh
shift
newusernames=$(printf '%s' "$*")
```

In Bash, you'd have fancier options such as

```sh
printf -v newusernames '%s' "${*:2}"
```

to do everything in one step.